# How to optimize memory while running app on iPhone simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios7

I am new iPhone development and my app goes crashed when doing navigation of pages for multiple times in simulator.
In Debug Session when it reaches 50MB, my app goes crashed.
What could be the possible solutions to stop crashing ?

Comment: Are you sure it's running out of memory? 50MB is not a particularly high memory usage for an app - it's likely that you have some other problem.

Comment: Yes it is crashing. I am not getting exception. I am using simulator iOS7.1

Comment: solution cant be possible without seeing your code

Comment: Can any body suggest how can I observe memory occupation per page?

Comment: If you are sure that this is memory issue: First - try static analyser(cmd+shift+b), it may show something, although after ARC appeared it's become not so useful. Then use leaks instrument provided by Xcode. If you fix all leaks that appear there and still experience memory problems - second tool which comes with Leaks(second row) is Allocations(first row). Use "Mark Generations" to see, what is causing troubles.
If it's not a memory: use Zombies instrument to see if you are trying to use dead object. 
For both cases: enable "exceptions breakpoint". 
Also post iOS version and if ARC is on.

Comment: @TimurKuchkarov Thanks for suggesting tools, analyser helps me to remove unused variables, also trying other tools.

Comment: @TimurKuchkarov I am using iOS 7.1 and Yes ARC is enabled.